# when do children start answering questions ?

Tags: language-development, language

My child is 2.5 years old. He understands two step instructions and expresses himself.

However, he does not answers questions. For example: if I ask *where is your mom?* he will not answer that *she is in the kitchen*.

When do kids start answering questions like these?

Comment: Two challenges there-- using full sentences & cognitively understanding the informational content of the question. And there are lots of kinds of questions. Can you point at the cat? vs Why is the cat hiding? I would guess the type of question would make a big difference.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the information [from this site](http://teachmetotalk.com/2008/02/26/techniques-to-work-on-answering-questions-with-language-delayed-toddlers/) children are usually able to answer simple questions (like the example you have given) by the time they reach 3. At 2.5 years most children are able to answer most yes/no questions. You can also find hints how to improve your child's answering skills.

Remember that each child is different. One may start doing something earlier than other, but start doing something else later.

I think there is no reason to worry yet. But if you are in doubt or already worried, do not hesitate to consult your pediatrician.